# Is there something like Tasker (Android) for Ubuntu

Tags: 13.04, software-recommendation, automation

Is there something like Tasker (android app for automating things) for Ubuntu 13.04 (cuttlefish ruled out)?

Comment: why dont you want to use cuttlefish?

Comment: @fossfreedom 13.04 </3 cuttlefish. Uses outdated stuff, and is a 12.04 only ppa.

Answer (score 1):

If you're discarding cuttlefish because is not available for 13.04, you could install the 12.04 version manually. First you must download and install its dependences:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+package/liblaunchpad-integration-common
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+package/liblaunchpad-integration-3.0-1
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+package/gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0

Then add the 12.04 cuttlefish ppa to your source list and later install it:

```
echo ' deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/noneed4anick/cuttlefish/ubuntu precise main ' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuttlefish
```

Comment: True, but eventually, it needs fixing to not use said old stuff.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser At least for me, in the meantime that I wait a version for raring, it works great